# Building external library from source in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to figure out how to set up my visual studio solution so that I can build boost from source and use the resulting .lib in the solutions's projects.

I know that I can create a new project for boost in my solution, and copy the source files into that, but because of the file size I'd rather keep them out of my solution folder.

What I was thinking then is to put the source files for boost in an external lib folder, then point the boost project to the lib folder so that it can build them.

I can't figure out how to do this though. Is there any way to build source files in an external directory in visual studio? I know that there's an option to include existing files, which sort of works. The problem is that it doesn't seem to include any files in child directories, so that's no good for me.

Is this even a good idea?

Comment: You can automate this with `CMake`.

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with it. Does it work alongside VS's build tools or does it replace it? WIll it also make it easier to build on other platforms witrhout visual studio?

Comment: It works with VS build tools. And yes it will certianly make it easier to build on other platforms without Visual Studio. However there is a learning curve..

Comment: Thanks for point me in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can install boost  selected or all libraries in just a one liner command using vcpkg.exe . You can also build other open source libraries for x86 or x64 target platforms. All the libraries will be automatically included in your visual studio projects. Example of usage(to be typed on Powershell prompt): .\vcpkg install boost-thread:x64-windows .